# Opening url in the last open tab in chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser

I am getting an issue while opening URL in my default browser (Chrome)

My requirement is opening URL in the last open tab in Chrome browser for 4.4.4 (Chrome is default browser). NOT in a new tab.

Below code is opening URL in a new tab:

```
Intent mBrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mBrowserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);                                           mBrowserIntent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID,mContext.getPackageName());                    mBrowserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
mBrowserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);             
mBrowserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mUrl));
mContext.startActivity(mBrowserIntent);
```

Please help in resolving this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by same tab? Do you mean the last open tab?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, note that you should not use getPackageName():

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://yahoo.com"));
intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, "com.android.browser");
startActivty(intent);
```

EDIT: I just tested it on 4.2.2, and it works.

Comment: I am testing in moto g with same. It is opening in new Tab.

Comment: Did you use "com.android.browser" ?

Comment: My requirement is, suppose I browse www.yahoo.com in one tab of chrome browser. I am making user not to view that content by opening other url in same tab