# Android open link in Mozilla Firefox app in the current open tab

Tags: android, firefox, android-intent, webkit, android-browser

I have a very specific requirement: I need to open a URL link in a browser (not in a `WebView`), and I need it to open in the currently open tab, i.e. the opened page should be a "*redirect*" (meaning in the same tab).

Based on a consensus of multiple SO posts (see below), the way to do this is as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, packageName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Specifically it is [`Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser#EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID) that instructs the browser to open the link in the same tab:

[image]

Now in theory, this is supposed to work with all browsers.

> Here it is important to note that `packageName` above needs to be the package name of the **BROWSER** that one wishes to open (e.g. `com.android.chrome` or `org.mozilla.firefox`), not the package name of your app.
>
> Even though the documentation asks that you use the package name of
>   your own app, it doesn't open the link in the *currently open tab* if you use the
>   package name of your own app. Both Chrome & Firefox will open the link
>   in a new tab.

So the trick to getting this to work is to set `packageName` as `com.android.chrome`, and voilà, Chrome opens the link in the currently open tab. *Yay!*

The same trick does not work with Firefox.

***How can I make this work generally with any/all browsers?***

Apparently this is a known issue with Firefox:

**A**. [**Firefox doesn't handle the flag `Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID` from an Intent**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1340478).

**B**. [**Android Mozilla FireFox not opening page in a new tab**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47235365/3287204).

Has this bug been fixed? Is there a known way to make Firefox open the link in the same tab?

How can I make this work for any/all browsers?

**References**:

**1**. [**Is there any way in Android to force open a link to open in Chrome?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12013416/3287204).

**2**. [**Android open browser from service avoiding multiple tabs**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7197133/3287204).

**3**. [**Open an url in android browser, avoid multiple tabs**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5489086/3287204).

**4**. [**Opening url in the last open tab in chrome**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26879683/3287204).

**5**. [**Open url in same tab in browser using android code(not using webview)**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42249796/3287204).

**6**. [**Android app opening browser in the same tab?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36823802/3287204).

**7**. [**Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID not working in ICS**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9918091/3287204).

**8**. [**How to Stop Multiple Tabs Opened in Browser**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49306595/3287204).

**9**. [**How to Avoid Loading Local Page in New Tab on Default Android Browser**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9221725/3287204).

**10**. [**Handle tab queues with Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1161667).

**11**. [**Allow loading URI Intents**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=851693).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be supported; [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L56) shows the `intent-filter` ... and `newTab = session == null` and `newTab = true` are hard-coded. Unless this gets filed as a feature request - or an eventual PR, which enables this will get merged, this won't happen (and even then, it would only be supported in later versions).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, Martin. I'm still hopeful this is doable. If it works with Chrome, there just may be a way to make it work with Firefox.

Comment: @Y.S when the source code does not support that, how shall it pick up the `Intent`? Firefox is not magic... you could only use `WebView` & `GeckoView` for a consistent behavior (which is useless, when it shall be the default browser). Expecting identical behavior from the default browser is probably asked a little much.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of firefox try the below workaround by setting the component to intent.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.mozilla.firefox","org.mozilla.firefox.App"));
 this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This does not work. Moreover, you haven't included `Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_EXTRA_ID`, but even with that it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox appears to have fixed this just fine.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setPackage("org.mozilla.firefox");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(link));
intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, "MySpecialTab");
```

Note that it's better to use `setPackage` than `setComponent` as Mozilla has changed the actual activity name over time. The `EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID` is no such thing. If you want to reuse two tabs for many links call one "Interesting" and the other "Boring".

Comment: Yeah, but Mozilla broke it when they changed from the "Fennec" platform to "Fenix".
See: https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/4106
Last Fennec version is here: https://download.mozilla.org/?product=fennec-latest&os=android&lang=multi